# How to log to event viewer when Default Web Site restarted in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, logging, iis, events

I have an ASP.NET web page running under IIS. I have a requirement where I need to log to event viewer when the webpage is restarted through IIS manager.  I am not sure if this can be done through ASP.NET or can I turn on some options in IIS to capture the restart? Please help!

Comment: In addition to the configuration mentioned by Malvik Bhavsar, you also need to enable ETW event in the Logging feature so that you can view it. double-click Logging in the Connections pane, Under Log Event Destination, select ETW event only, or, if you want the log information sent to both ETW and the log file, select Both log file and ETW event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS Manager check the following configuration:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Go application pools.
3. Select the application pool, right-click and select "Advanced Settings".
4. Under Recycling, Expand "Generate Recycle Event Log Entry"

[image]